# Generar un certificado .cert y .key?

Tags: tomcat, certificado-ssl, keystore

Soy muy novato en la generación y el funcionamiento de los certificados.
Una empresa x necesita que su pagina sea segura (https), para eso sé que necesitan un certificado, cuando les pido que me den el certificado ellos me envían 3 archivos:

```
(certificate.ca.crt ; certificate.crt ; certificate.key)
```

Debo mencionar que no debería ser un certificado autofirmado!
el certificado le debo agregar en mi servidor Tomcat!

Mi pregunta es cómo construyo mi certificado a partir de estos 3 archivos?
Además como se que no son certificados auto-firmados y que sí es dado o construido por alguna autoridad de certificación?

Answer (score 2):

Los certificados SSL deben estar emitidos por una [entidad autorizada](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoridad_de_certificaci%C3%B3n), en caso contrario los navegadores te marcarán que el sitio no es seguro.

Si tu cliente no desea comprar un certificado aún, el siguiente sitio emite certificados gratuitos y autorizados por periodos cortos, no requieres mucho conocimiento para hacerlo:

https://www.sslforfree.com/

Respecto a los archivos:

certificate.ca.crt --> Certificado de la entidad Certificadora

certificate.crt --> Certificado de tu sitio (llave pública)

certificate.key --> Llave privada

Este sitio de Google te puede ayudar mucho para empezar:
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/

Lamentablemente no puedo ayudarte mucho con Tomcat, pero te dejo algunas referencias que tal ves puedan servirte:

[Apache Tomcat SSL/TLS Configuration HOWTO](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html)

[Installing SSL Apache Tomcat](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9441/0/tomcat-using-keytool)

[Cómo obtener un certificado SSL para su dominio - Ayuda de Google Domains](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/7630973?hl=es-419)

[Let's Encrypt Entidad Certificadora gratuita](https://letsencrypt.org/es/)

Comment: Muchas gracias por el comentario en realidad necesitaba la configuración en tomcat y un entendimiento mas sobre los certificados, tu comentario me guio en muchas cosas mas tarde publicare mi respuesta.

Comment: Un gusto poderte ayudar, si la respuesta te sirvió por favor no olvides marcarla con palomita, saludos

Answer (score 0):

Mi entendimiento y solución:
Estaba dando vueltas en la red y esto es lo que investigue:

Esto mostrará información de la entidad certificadora como el dominio del certificado y demás información:
 `openssl x509 -in certificate.crt -text`

Para crear el keystore(p12), convertir en cert en PKCS12 usando openssl

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in [my_certificate.crt] -inkey [my_key.key] -out [keystore.p12] -name [new_alias] -CAfile [my_ca_bundle.crt] -caname root
```

- También pueden usar una herramienta (.jar) para crear el keystore http://portecle.sourceforge.net/ (opcional)
- Para la configuración del Tomcat,parar el tomcat, editar el archivo server.xml (../tomcat7/conf/server.xml) algo así:

  ```
      <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true" maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
         clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
         keystoreFile="/RutaAlArchivo/keystore.p12" keystorePass="password"/>
  ```
- Correr el tomcat.